# What does scanf("%*[\n] %[^\n]" do?

Tags: c

What does scanf("%*[\n] %[^\n]" means, How is it differs form %s for char phrases input? I cant understand the difference, What does it exactly means?

Comment: it doesn't break when meets space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does scanf("%\*\[\n\] %\[^\n\]", input\_string); do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278383/what-does-scanf-n-n-input-string-do)